# Should a celery task save django model updates immediately?

Tags: django, celery

I have a celery task that runs for five minutes at a time to check an azure service bus subscription topic for messages.   Throughout the five minutes, it pings the service bus every second to check for a message, and if it finds one, it saves some info to a database.  I`ve noticed that the actual commit to the database only occurs when the task ends at the five minute mark, and not when the model.save() method is called.

I'm wondering, is it a good idea to add some code to force each save to occur immediately, instead of at the end of the five minutes?  I`m thinking of using a statement that involves atomic transactions to accomplish this.

The code below contains my task. I use a while loop to keep the task going for 5 minutes, and inside it, I ping the service bus for messages every second, and then save them if found.

```py
class CheckForUpdates(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = 300

    def run(self, queue_name='bus_queue'):
        end_task_time = _at_five_minutes()
        while time.time() < end_task_time:
            _wait_for_one_second()
            result = _check_service_bus_for_update()
            if _update_was_found(result):
                update = json.loads(result.body)
                logger.info("azure response body: ", update)
                # code that updates a django model
                model.save()
```

Is this a good design?  It is ok to let the database commits accumulate for 5 minutes and then save them all consecutively at the end of the 5 minutes?  Should I use transactions, or force the task to save immmediately every time?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the signal of the models in Django, that way you can wait to listen  for a signal from databases `django.db.models.signals` had some hook that you can use, that way you can just wait for the event happen, I will post an example:

```
signal.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from pay.models import RateDeck

@receiver(post_save, sender=RateDeck)
def post_save_RateDeck(sender, instance, **kwargs):
idpk = instance.pk
transaction.on_commit(lambda :uploadrate.apply_async(args=[idpk]))
```

So I hope that you get that `uploadrate` is a function that is called when the transaction is completed `transaction.on_commit` send the signal when the transaction in databases is done.